# Binary Search Tree insert method fails to insert any nodes

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a BST, it sets the `root` value again to `None` after the call to `insert()` has been executed, when it should be changed to the first value inserted after the first call and create a tree afterwards. Any suggestions on why this is happening?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


def insert(root,value):
    if root is None:
        root = Node(value)
        print(1)
    elif value <= root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, value)
        print(2)
    else:
        root.right = insert(root.right, value)
        print(3)


def search(root,value):
    if root is None:
        print("False")
    elif root.value == value:
        print("True")
    elif value <= root.value:
        return search(root.left, value)
    else:
        return search(root.right, value)


root = None

insert(root,15)
insert(root,10)
insert(root,25)

search(root,10)
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make an assignment such as `root = Node(value)` in a function, it doesn't modify the `root` object in the outer scope as you might expect. Instead, it reassigns the local `root` variable inside the `insert` function to a new `Node` object, which goes out of scope when the function returns.

One solution is to return the new root object which you've created and reassign it in the calling scope, overwriting the value of the old root. This is also important for recursive assignments so that `.left` and `.right` properties are set correctly.

Here's the fixed code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


def insert(root,value):
    if root is None:
        root = Node(value)
        print(1)
    elif value <= root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, value)
        print(2)
    else:
        root.right = insert(root.right, value)
        print(3)

    return root
    #^^^^^^^^^^


def search(root,value):
    if root is None:
        print("False")
    elif root.value == value:
        print("True")
    elif value <= root.value:
        return search(root.left, value)
    else:
        return search(root.right, value)


root = None
root = insert(root,15)
#^^^^^^
root = insert(root,10)
root = insert(root,25)
search(root,10)
search(root,15)
search(root,25)
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
1
3
True
True
True
```

---

I'd also recommend eliminating prints from inside your functions, although I understand you're likely in debug mode. Here's a quick cleanup:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


def insert(root,value):
    if not root:
        root = Node(value)
    elif value <= root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, value)
    else:
        root.right = insert(root.right, value)

    return root

def search(root, value):
    if not root:
        return False
    elif root.value == value:
        return True
    elif value <= root.value:
        return search(root.left, value)

    return search(root.right, value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = None
    root = insert(root, 15)
    root = insert(root, 10)
    root = insert(root, 25)
    root = insert(root, 27)
    print(root, root.left, root.right, root.right.right)
    print(search(root, 10))
    print(search(root, 15))
    print(search(root, 25))
    print(search(root, 27))
    print(search(root, 12))
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the same thing before but forgot to add the return statement.